# Tag badge on zero score accepted answer

Tags: support, tag-badges, score, zero-score-badges

I searched in previous questions but didn't find an answer about earning the "Tag badge".

If my answer was accepted without upvotes, does it not help me get the desired tag badge?  (I did earn the "unsung hero" budge which is nice).

If, for example, my answer was accepted with a score of zero, and some other answer got +1, is that other user one step closer to the the badge even though my answer is the accepted one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Your score in a tag is calculated as the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes on *answers* (not questions) to questions having that tag. Whether an answer is accepted or not **does not matter at all** for tag scores.